Fixed coordinate is shifting in each frame of the animation
I am trying to animate a rotating coordinate system around fixed cartesian coordinates. The fixed coordinate system keeps shifting in each frame as the rotating coordinate system rotates.
I am attaching the codes I used. Here, f is a function that gives Euler angles from NDSolve. m is Eulermatrix.
Export["movie2.avi",ParallelTable[Show[Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,0,3.5}}]},Boxed->False],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,3.5,0}}]}],
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],Arrow[{{0,0,0},{3.5,0,0}}]}],Graphics3D[{Text[Style[x,FontSize->20],{3.8,0,0}]}],Graphics3D[{Text[Style[y,FontSize->20],{0,3.8,0}]}],
Graphics3D[{Text[Style[z,FontSize->20],{0,0,3.8}]}],
Graphics3D[{Red,Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],GeometricTransformation[Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,0,2.5}}],Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]}],
Graphics3D[{Red,Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],GeometricTransformation[Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,2.5,0}}],Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]}],
Graphics3D[{Red,Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],GeometricTransformation[Arrow[{{0,0,0},{2.5,0,0}}],Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]}],
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[{Text[Style[z,FontSize->15,Red],{0,0,2.6}]},Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]],
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[{Text[Style[y,FontSize->15,Red],{0,2.6,0}]},Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]],
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[{Text[Style[x,FontSize->15,Red],{2.6,0,0}]},Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]],
ViewPoint->{2,1.0,0.5}(*,ImageSize\[Rule]{1280,720},ImageMargins->{{5,5},{5,5}}*)

],{T,0,time}]];

I have also attached a short animation showing the fixed coordinate changing its center at each frame.

f , m and time are not defined.

Use SphericalRegion->True and if needed also use explicit PlotRange.

Thank you @azerbajdzan, this suppose to work. But, the problem doesn't seem to be going away.

Boy... this is about the most inefficient code I've seen on this site... every graphics element wrapped in its own Graphics3D environment indeed!!

Try ViewVector->{{5,5,5},{0,0,0}} instead of ViewPoint

@DavidG.Stork I agree with you. It is very inefficient code. I am uploading the modified code.

I have got the desired result by using @Lexington1776's suggetion. Thank you.

Too long for a comment:
@SanGu:  Study this code to see the first steps for reducing your second posting by at least 50%:
Graphics3D[{
  (Text[Style[#[[1]], FontSize -> 20], #[[2]]] & /@
    {{"x", {3.8, 0, 0}}, {"y", {0, 3.8, 0}}, {"z", {0, 0, 3.8}}}),
  Thickness[0.003], 
  Arrowheads[0.03], 
 (Arrow /@ {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3.5}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 3.5, 0}}, 
 {{0, 0, 0}, {3.5, 0, 0}}})
  }
 ]


Here is the code, after the implementation of everyone's suggestions.
Export["movie.gif",{Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,0,3.5}}]},{Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,3.5,0}}]},{Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],Arrow[{{0,0,0},{3.5,0,0}}]},{Text[Style[x,FontSize->20],{3.8,0,0}]},{Text[Style[y,FontSize->20],{0,3.8,0}]},{Text[Style[z,FontSize->20],{0,0,3.8}]},
{Red,Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],GeometricTransformation[Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,0,2.5}}],Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]},
{Red,Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],GeometricTransformation[Arrow[{{0,0,0},{0,2.5,0}}],Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]},
{Red,Thickness[0.003],Arrowheads[0.03],GeometricTransformation[Arrow[{{0,0,0},{2.5,0,0}}],Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]},
GeometricTransformation[{Text[Style[z,FontSize->15,Red],{0,0,2.6}]},Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]],
GeometricTransformation[{Text[Style[y,FontSize->15,Red],{0,2.6,0}]},Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]],
GeometricTransformation[{Text[Style[x,FontSize->15,Red],{2.6,0,0}]},Transpose[Flatten[m/.f,1]]]

},
SphericalRegion->True,
ViewVector->{{8,8,8},{0,0,0}},
Boxed->False],{T,0,time}]]


Two things:  1) If you create equivalent code, use it to replace the inefficient code in the ORIGINAL posting.  It is very very confusing to have TWO separate questions, where one is an "answer"!  2) Your code is still extremely inefficient.  Anytime you see repeated definitions such as Red, Thickness[], etc., it shows you're being inefficient.  I think your latest code can be reduced by at least 50%.  Try it!  e.g.:  {Thickness[0.003], Arrowheads[0.03], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 3.5, 0}}],   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {3.5, 0, 0}}]}

Run this code:  Graphics3D[{  Text[Style[#[[1]], FontSize -> 20], #[[2]]] & /@   {{"x", {3.8, 0, 0}}, {"y", {0, 3.8, 0}}, {"z", {0, 0, 3.8}}}],{Thickness[0.003], Arrowheads[0.03], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 3.5, 0}}],   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {3.5, 0, 0}}]}].

Thank you @DavidG.Stork, I really appriciate the help.
